# JavaScript Array Min Value Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, slice, lastindexof

It give me correct index when i give fixed array i.e

```
BT_input = [11, 10, 10, 14]
```

But when i get array values from user this Return -1 instead of correct index ?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
const BT_input = [];
var size = 3;
 for(var a=0; a<=size; a++) 
{
      BT_input[a] = prompt('Enter Brust Time of P ' + (a));
}
function sayHello() {
  var indexMenor = BT_input.indexOf(Math.min(...BT_input));
  
  document.write(indexMenor);
}

sayHello();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use parseFloat function to convert the user strings inputs to numbers

Comment: The code suffers multiple problems.

Answer (score -1):

you need to translate the string to number

like this

```js
const BT_input = [];
var size = 3;
 for(var a=0; a<size; a++) 
{
      BT_input[a] = Number(prompt('Enter Brust Time of P ' + (a)));
}
function sayHello() {
  var indexMenor = BT_input.indexOf(Math.min(...BT_input));
  
  document.write(indexMenor);
}

sayHello()
```

Comment: Thanks man! it was my 1st question on stackoverflow and i am impressed by comunity